# making ajax request in meteor helpers

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor

How can i wait until the ajax request finishes when returning data to a meteor helpers method.

For example,

```
Template.item.helpers({

        itemName:function () {
            var user = Meteor.user();

            $.when(reallyLongAjaxRequest()).done(function (a1) {
               //tried using jquery when
                return "Item Name should have this because it waited";
            });

            return " Doesnt wait at all";
        }
    });
```

I have a `reallyLongAjaxRequest()` running and i would like it to finish before continuing on with my itemName helper. The log statement to console always shows undefined but that's because the ajax request hasn't finished. I tried using the jquery when with no luck. Any ideas

Edit:

I should mention that i am inside the helper function for a reason. I need the item 'id' being rendered so that i can run the ajax request with that paramater. Using reactive sessions would be perfect but i don't know of a way to get currently rendering items outside of the helpers method definition?

Comment: You must divide your function. One part before the request and another after. On XMLHttpObject you can handle the [events](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#events)

Comment: not sure i follow you. Is this in conjunction with using the $.when method?

Comment: I don't know Meteor Api, so I'm proposing workaround with bare XMLHTTP request. I may be very wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An unnamed collection is one where `null` is passed for the name.  It is an in-memory data structure, not saved to the database.  (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection)

OK, given a Meteor collection called "items" and wanting to do an ajax request for each item based on the item _id, and then being able to reference the ajax result in a template, this is what I'd do:

(roughly)

```
var Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');
var Results = new Meteor.Collection(null);

Items.find().observeChanges({
  added: function (id) {
    $.get(url, {id: id}, function (data) {
      if (Results.findOne(id))
        Results.update(id, {$set: {result: data}});
      else
        Results.insert({_id: id, result: data});
    });
  }
});

Template.item.itemName = function (id) {
  var doc = Results.findOne(id);
  if (doc)
    return doc.result;
  else
    return "";
};
```

inside your html you'll need to pass in the id to the helper:

```
{{itemName _id}}
```

*Is there no way to just timeout for a few seconds when defining the helper so that my ajax request finishes without immediately returning.*

No, with reactive programming things happen immediately, but you update when you have new stuff.

Comment: never mind. Thanks again for helping me think outside the box. Also, the id doesn't have to be in the helper. You can retrieve the id using this._id inside the helper definition, i also had to move the observe changes call inside a meteor.startup because of the way i define my collections, meteor couldn't find 'Items' & 'Results'

Comment: I hate to come back to this but because this is an in memory data structure, when i stop and start meteor. The result property in Results isn't there and i have to manually refresh to get that data. Anything within meteor i can do to run right away?

Answer (score 1):

Make your ajax request separately, and when it completes, have it store the result in a Session variable.  Then have your template helper return the value of the Session variable.  Roughly...

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
  Session.set('result', data);
});

Template.item.itemName = function () {
  return Session.get('result');
};
```

Session is a reactive data source, so your template will automatically updated when the result of the ajax call comes in.  (Naturally you can choose to call the Session variable anything you like, I just used "result" as an example).

Comment: The ajax request uses the item _id as parameter to make the ajax request. When i am displaying my items, i grab each item id, get data from it and make an ajax request to a data source to get more data. How can i for each item make an ajax request without being inside the item to get the field this._id ?

Comment: Where are the items coming from?  If they're coming from a Collection, then what I'd do is add an `observe` to the collection, and when an item was added, I'd fire off the ajax request at that point.

A little more tricky is then getting the particular item's result into the item's template.  An easy though somewhat inelegant way to do it would be to store the result in a session variable named "result_" concatenated with the id.

Comment: Well, actually, I'd probably use an unnamed collection to hold the item results.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by unnamed collection to hold item results ? I am using a meteor collection 'item' to hold all items and doing the standard #each iteration to display the items. Is there no way to just timeout for a few seconds when defining the helper so that my ajax request finishes without immediately returning. Any sort of meteor call back i could attach to after the fact so that i still have access to each individual item

Answer (score -1):

This works and tested in MeteorJS > 1.3.x

Add the http package from the console `meteor add http`

Example POST call with data elements being sent to server and with custom headers.

```
HTTP.call('POST', tokenUri, {
    data: {
        "type": 'authorization_code',
        //"client_id": clientId,
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri" : redirectUri,

    },
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    }
},function(error, response) {
    if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    } else {
        console.log( response );
    }
});
```